# Stop div appearing after FadeIn upon scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using fadeIn on a div

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
   $('.bottomMenu_alert').fadeIn();
});
```

The user can close the div by clicking anywhere outside the div by using

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
        if ( !$(event.target).hasClass('.bottomMenu_alert')) {
             $(".bottomMenu_alert").hide();
        }
    });
```

But when the user scrolls again the div reappears.

How can I stop the div reappearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a simple flag variable to lock the div and only fade it in if it is not locked. See this:

```
var divLocked = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
   if (!divLocked) {  // show only if not locked
       $('.bottomMenu_alert').fadeIn();
   }
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ( !$(event.target).hasClass('.bottomMenu_alert')) {
         $(".bottomMenu_alert").hide();
         divLocked = true;   // lock it after the first click
    }
});
```